# TikZ: Drawing edges between subgraphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I have this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\tikz
\graph [simple, nodes={draw, circle, minimum size = .5cm}, clockwise] {
  subgraph C_n [name=inner, radius = 1.5cm, n=3];
  subgraph C_n [name=outer, radius = 3cm, n=4];
};

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now I want to draw single edges from nodes of `inner` to nodes of `outer`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the names `inner` and `outer` as prefix for the node numbers:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [simple, nodes={draw, circle, minimum size = .5cm}, clockwise] 
{
  subgraph C_n [name=inner, radius = 1.5cm, n=3];
  subgraph C_n [name=outer, radius = 3cm, n=4];
};
\draw
 (inner 1) -- (outer 2)
 (inner 3) -- (outer 4)
 (inner 2) -- (outer 4)
 (inner 3) -- (outer 1)
 (inner 2) -- (outer 3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Of course, you can also use the `edge` path:

```
\path
 (inner 1) edge (outer 2)
 (inner 3) edge (outer 4)
 (inner 2) edge (outer 4)
 (inner 3) edge (outer 1)
 (inner 2) edge (outer 3);
```